# How to avoid creating column on database, ERP

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Now I have a problem with my source code. I am using EntityFramework.6.1.3.
I have a Model folder, and in this folder I have  `Product.cs`. Here is content of  `Product.cs` file.

```
[Data]
[Column(TypeName = "numeric"), Display(Name = "ProductUnitPrice")]
public decimal ProductUnitPrice { get; set; }
```

When I run the application, ProductUnitPrice column will automatically be created in my DB. However, because I run migration before I run this project, I don't want ProductUnitPrice to be created in my DB
I tried `[NotMapped]` but it does not work.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Actually `[NotMapped]` should work for you. do you have separate `EntityConfiguration` in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: Howcan separate `EntityConfiguration` in `OnModelCreating`? May be I did not do it